# Deserializing List of JSON does the Data Contract have to have every member the JSON has?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

Hey guys I am trying to deserialize a JSON response from an API then display the data. I am getting the response back in the form of a string and trying to map it to an object. This is a response from twitter and it responds with multiple tweets, so I am trying to map it to a list of tweets.

I am receiving the following exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Type 'Default3+TwitterApiData' is not supported for deserialization of an array. at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input) at Default3.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Could this potentially be because I do not have data members for every Key value pair in the JSON? The JSON returned is like 60 KV pairs and I do not need all the data so I just have two members.

Or an I doing something potentially wrong with deserializing to an array of objects? Below is my code that is doing the deserialization.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resourceUrl);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            var responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            TwitterApiData twitterApiResponse = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TwitterApiData>(responseData);

            foreach (var item in twitterApiResponse.data)
            {
                lblResponse.InnerText = "created_at: " + item.created_at + " text: " + item.text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblResponse.InnerText = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Then my object I am mapping to. Also looking at this do I need [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes?

```
public class TwitterApiData
{
    public List<Tweet> data { get; set; }
}

public class Tweet
{
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    TwitterApiData data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TwitterApiData>(strContent);
```

Comment: You just renamed the variables/ objects I am using? That is the exact line I have already.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I did not need the wrapped object. I just deserialized it into a list of tweets.

```
var twitterApiResponse = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Tweet>>(responseData);
```

Sorted.